# Route returning Error 404 but the route exists

Tags: laravel

I have a blade template where I call a route to the show method:

```
<div class="user"><a href="{{ route('profile.show',$user->id) }}"><div><img src="{{asset('images/user.svg')}}" alt=""></div></a></div>
```

That route is controlled by a resource controller and the routes are set like this:

```
Route::resource('profile', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController')->middleware('auth');
```

All the routes of that controller are defined as you can see from the output of my `php artisan route:list`:

```
    |        | GET|HEAD  | profile                     | profile.index     | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@index                            | web        |
    |        |           |                             |                   |                                                                        | auth       |
    |        | POST      | profile                     | profile.store     | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@store                            | web        |
    |        |           |                             |                   |                                                                        | auth       |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | profile/create              | profile.create    | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@create                           | web        |
    |        |           |                             |                   |                                                                        | auth       |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | profile/{profile}           | profile.show      | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@show                             | web        |
    |        |           |                             |                   |                                                                        | auth       |
    |        | DELETE    | profile/{profile}           | profile.destroy   | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@destroy                          | web        |
    |        |           |                             |                   |                                                                        | auth       |
    |        | PUT|PATCH | profile/{profile}           | profile.update    | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@update                           | web        |
    |        |           |                             |                   |                                                                        | auth       |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | profile/{profile}/edit      | profile.edit      | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@edit                             | web        |
    |        |           |                             |                   |                                                                        | auth       |
```

So far the controller only has a dd function since I haven't started writing it yet and the show method is the only one with anything written yet:

```
public function show($id)
{ dd($id);}
```

But for some reason, whenever I try acessing that route, it returns a 404 Not Found error. I tried accessing the index method and it works, but the show method always returns the 404 Not Found error. I also tried `php artisan route:clear` but it didn't solve the problem. What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: `php artisan route:clear` then try again, hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Already tried that, but it still doesn't work, sorry, should have said that in the post.

Comment: do you see your route on route list? `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Yes, it's all there

Comment: Check the controller show function, may be 404 raises from there

Comment: Does it raise the 404 for only one user or for all users?

Comment: Which one laravel version ?

Comment: The controller is okay, it worked before. The laravel version is 8.8.0

Comment: Can you add the controller code also (show function)

Comment: Controller added

Comment: There are no any parameter called `$id` it should be `public function show($profile)`

Comment: I didn't create that. Laravel created the controller like that. It was Laravel who added that $id. I just used a php artisan create:controller --resource

Comment: @GustavoAraújo change it to `public function show($profile)` and let me update of `dd($profile);`

Answer (score 0):

Try out it , list all of router

```
php artisan route:list
```

Or you can as such that

```php
Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController', [
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'show.show'
        'store' => 'profile.new',
        
    ]
]);
```

Comment: I added the route:list to question, sorry for not adding it before

Comment: Declare resource route as mine and again try out! php artisan route:list

Answer (score 0):

And if you try this ?

```
<div class="user"><a href="{{ route('profile.show', ['profile' => $user->id]) }}"><div><img src="{{asset('images/user.svg')}}" alt=""></div></a></div>
```